# How to find repeated Rows?

Tags: mysql

i am having 75000  row records i need to get how many of them repeated,how can i do that in MySQL Query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This query will return all duplicate rows, and the number of times they are duplicated

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,..ColLast, Count(*) As NumDups FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Col1,Col2,...,ColLast
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```